# ComboBox SearchField and Primary Text drop downs are empty

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a ComboBox that i want to store a User record in (AAD User), and i want it to display the 'Display Name' property of the user record.

If i use 'AAD Users' as the "Items" property that appears to work, but i get a bunch of superfluous 'users' like 'information', 'orders' because the client has them created as users. And, not all users should be in the drop down.

So i have created a table (Personnel) that keeps track of which users should be in which dropdowns, it has a 'Role' and 'AadUser' column with Role being a Choice and AadUser being an AadUser. My goal was to use this code get the users in the combobox Items config:

// for populating the designers combobox

Filter(
Personnel,
Role = 'Role (Personnel)'.Designer
).AadUser

However the combobox only shows blank lines, and i can not set the Primary Text or SearchField properties.

Any thinghts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control items don't support nested objects. Try something like this:

```
ForAll(
  Filter( Personnel, Role = 'Role (Personnel)'.Designer ),
  ThisRecord.AadUser
)
```